# Override and equal method

Tags: java, oop

I have the emplyee class and i need to implement a method in this class that checks to see if two employees are equal meeaning they have the same ID and name attributes. Can someone please explain how i can use override and complete this method so the method can perform the equality check while using object as an input to the method. Also what would be a good test method for this.

```
package employees;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Represents an average employee working 40 hours per week.
 *
 * @author Megan Rigsbee (mrigsbee), JW Lee (jiayiw6)
 * @version 2019.09.01
 */
public class Employee {
    // ~ Fields ................................................................

    private String name;
    private int employeeId;
    private double hourlyRate;


    // ~ Constructor ...........................................................
    /**
     * New Employee object.
     *
     * @param name
     *            Name of Employee
     * @param employeeId
     *            Employee ID of Employee
     * @param hourlyRate
     *            Pay rate of Employee (per hour).
     */
    public Employee(String name, int employeeId, double hourlyRate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;
    }

    // ~ Methods ...............................................................


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Gets the employee's name.
     * 
     * @return the employee's name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Gets the employee's employee identifier.
     * 
     * @return the employee's employee identifier
     */
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Gets the pay rate (per hour).
     * 
     * @return the pay rate
     */
    public double getHourlyRate() {
        return hourlyRate;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Amount paid to the employee for an average 40 hour work week.
     * 
     * @return weekly Weekly pay for employee
     */
    public double weeklyPay() {
        return hourlyRate * 40;
    }
    
    
    @Override

    public boolean equals(Object obj)

    {
        return false;

        //Implementation goes here.

    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast the parameter. Then you can check for equality

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)

{
  if (!obj instanceof YourClass) {
    return false;
  }
  YourClass yc = (YourClass) obj;
  ...
    //Implementation goes here.

}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is far away from how the proper `equals` method should be implemented